# How to run "source" command in C++

Tags: c++, shell

I have a C++ application, and I want the application to always run one of my scripts with source.

I used:

```
system("source myscript");
```

but it doesn't work and does not recognize the "source" command. If I omit "source" myscript will execute but with source it doesn't work.

Is there any solution to run source command in C++?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? (i.e. what that script does, and why you're trying to source it from C++?) In short, there's no way to do that directly. Depending on what the script actually does, there will be different options from the C++ side.

Comment: this makes no sense at all. You can run an executable (like `c++`) using `system()`, but not a shell command (like `source`). This would make no sense.

Comment: @Mat My application uses dbus, I want to ssh my application and I have to set environment variable DBUS in source to have access to my application in target of ssh. I wrote a script that sets the DBUS environment variable, and I want my application to set it automatically. means that I want when anyone who ssh the target, and runs my app in target, automatically "source myscript" runs in source so he can access dbus too.

Comment: The easiest for that is to do it the other way around. Write a small shell wrapper that sources your script then execs your C++ app.

Comment: @Mat would you please explain what this shell wrapper is? I wrote another script that sources this script, but it didn't work again. I mean it didn't source in ssh source!(when I called it from ssh source)

Comment: Write a shell script that does `source myscript ; exec your_cpp_app;`, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't invoke `source` using `system` because it is a shell-builtin and not an actual executable.

If you want to source a shell script's variables, you'll have to somehow get at the variables set in the script another way. One way would be to write a wrapper script that sources your script and then simply prints out all exported variables to stdout. Your C program could then invoke the wrapper script, iterate over the output line by line and set each of its environment variables to the value outputted by the script (this assumes that the wrapped script itself doesn't produce any output).

Answer (score 2):

`source` is a shell command, not an independent program. `source` executes a shell script in the current shell, allowing that script access to shell variables and functions in the current environment.

Your C++ program is not a shell and it doesn't make sense to execute a script in a completely different language "inside" your c++ program's process.